# How to not have test-path search through whole directory or work around

Tags: powershell

I have some pdf files that come zipped and I need to unzip them, and then save just first page. I have the unzip and the saving first page code working as it should. However, when I do the unzip, there are around 150 folders created out of 4000 that contain pdf and other format files inside like .txt, .csv, etc.  So my problem is I need to pull the pdf files out and move them to the main folder with the rest of the other pdfs so I can batch save the first page of each pdf.

Folder structure after unzip would be:

```
SecondStorage (main folder where all pdf end after unzip)
   -Folder containing pdf and another file
   -folder containing pdf and another file
   -pdf
   -pdf
```

The PDF are always one folder level past where the rest of the pdf are located.

I am trying to write a foreach loop that uses a test-path to see if the pdf already exists in the main folder and if it does not, then move it to the parent folder.  I keep having issues with test path telling me the pdf exists in the folder and therefore doesn't move the file.

Here is my code I am currently using

```
$ListFiles = get-childitem -path $SecondStorage -Recurse -Filter "*.pdf"
$ShortList = $ListFiles | Where-Object -Property Name -Like "20*.pdf"


foreach ($i in $ShortList)
    {
        if (Test-Path -Path "$SecondStorage\$($i.name)" )
        {
            Move-Item -Path $i.fullname -Destination $SecondStorage
        }
        else 
        {
            Write-Output "File already exists"
        }
    }
```

When code runs, it tells me the file already exists.  I was thinking I could use literalpath but I am missing something as I keep getting the same result.

Thanks for any suggestions you have, they are much appreciated.

Comment: It seems like your if condition is backwards. You are coding to move if the file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply flip your `if` statement. When testing to see if the file exists in the main folder, you want to output the text, not Move ;-)

```
if (Test-Path -Path "$SecondStorage\$($i.name)" )
{
    Write-Output "File already exists"
}
else 
{
    Move-Item -Path $i.fullname -Destination $SecondStorage
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hal9256 and AdminOfThings...been starring at this whole code process for a full day and felt like I was missing something obvious. Thanks for your time.